# RoboGuice: how to use RoboGuice-provided injections in my custom class?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-contentresolver, roboguice

I've created a class that depends on a ContentResolver:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // these Injects won't work
    @Inject
    private ContentResolver m_contentResolver;

    @Inject
    public MyClass( ContentResolver resolver )
    {
        m_contentResolver = resolver;
    }

    [...]
}
```

ContentResolver is a RoboGuice-provided injection (https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/RoboGuice-Standard-Injections), but this assumes that I am using the injection in a class that extends a RoboGuice class such as RoboActivity.

Is there a way to use a RoboGuice-provided injection in my custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the constructor of MyClass: `RoboGuice.getInjector(myApplicationContext).injectMembers(this)`